# Are there any LEGO sets that have these two parts?

Tags: technic

Are there any LEGO sets that have the following parts:

- Part 57518 (Link Tread Wide with Two Pin Holes)

[image]

- Part 15035 / 18405 / 95292 (Large Shock Absorber with Very Hard Spring)

[image]

Comment: See related answer http://bricks.stackexchange.com/a/7895/7359 for an less expensive alternative to the shock absorber if size is not critical.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the spirit of "teach a man how to fish and he will have food for a lifetime", here is how you can find your own answer to this question.

1. Determine rarity of the parts by going to [BrickLink](http://www.bricklink.com) and search for the part name or number using the Catalog Search. BrickLink is a little finnicky with names and part numbers so it might take a few tries to get the right part (or to get it to return anything at all). For your items, [95292 only occurs in 3 sets](http://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=95292c01#T=C), whereas [57518 appears in 29 sets](http://www.bricklink.com/catalogItemIn.asp?P=57518&in=S).
2. You have several ways to go now - but the easiest is to have 2 tabs open, one for each of the list of sets. For each item in the shortest list, check if it occurs in the longer list (if the longer list is long, you can use Ctrl+F in your browser to do a text search on the page). Sorting each list by year might also help in doing this comparison.

For your selection of parts, it is quickly clear that **there is no set that contains both**. Not only that, the shock absorber you are looking for only occurred in 3 sets, all pretty limited in distribution (one of them being a truly Limited Edition of only 20k sets). Expect to be paying $10 per piece on BrickLink if you must have these. You might want to consider its shorter cousin [731c04 which occurs in 22 sets](http://www.bricklink.com/catalogItemIn.asp?P=731c04&in=S), including some lower-priced starter Technic sets. It can also be bought from many sellers on BrickLink for less than $2 per piece.