# LEGO Large Shock Absorber alternatives

Tags: technic

Are there cheaper alternatives to Large Shock Absorber with Very Hard Spring (Part No. 15035 / 18405 / 95292 / 95292c01)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per the answer to [your other question](https://bricks.stackexchange.com/questions/7892/are-there-any-lego-sets-that-have-these-two-parts), please consider part [731c04 - Yellow Technic, Shock Absorber 6.5L, Complete Assembly - Hard Spring](http://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=731c04#T=C). Not only is it still in production compared to 95292c01, it also has a much wider range of availability and hence costs you less to procure as a piece on BrickLink ($2 vs $10).

[image]